# .htaccess only allow if key is correct, and in URL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

My website has some PDF files stored in the web folders.

I do not want to show them of to the whole internet.
I want the PDF's only to be shown when they have a specific and correct key in the url like:
https://example.com/folder/test.pdf?authkey=123 or (Whatever key that is assigend in the MySQL db, each file has it's own specific key)

A PHP script declares the authkey to the file. And deletes the authkey after x hours.

How can this be achieved in .HTACCESS?

Other suggestions are welcome to!

Comment: Why not just move the pdfs outside of the project directory?

Comment: You want to allow file download?

Comment: @Andrei, because of some reasons. Some scirpts or pages view these of, but only when needed or the permission of the user is correct. But a direct link shows them of right now. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @nice_dev Yes and no, the files may be previewed when permission is okay, or they have a (what I call) access URL. Guests or persons who do not have the permission may not download the file directly, or even show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put all resource files outside of `public_html`(not mandatory, but a good practice).
- You can make a file accessible with a URL with 2 parameters: `file_name` and `auth_key`.
- Make a PHP script that receives this file, say `show_file.php` and check user's session in this file as to whether user is logged in or not. (session_start() and some key check in session, say `$_SESSION['user_logged_in']`).
- Put checks for `isset()` of both `file_name` and `auth_key` in your file in `$_GET` as to both params need to be supplied.
- Use PDO prepared statements to fire the DB with these 2 params in where condition.

  ```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("Select * from files where file_name = :file_name and auth_key = :auth_key");
  $stmt->bindParam(':file_name', $_GET['file_name']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':auth_key', $_GET['auth_key']);
  $stmt->execute();
  // further code
  ```
- If file record is found, get the file name and display it like below.

  ```
  header("Content-disposition:inline");
  header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");// or /pdf if serving only pdf files
  readfile($file_full_path);
  ```

This ensures files aren't accessible by any means from the web and you could also serve authorized users well.